# What is the name of a numerical title?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

For example, William Bank head was the 47nd Speaker of the House for the 74th congress.

Is there a word to describe 47 and 74?

Answer (score 1):

In this case you'd use "ordinal", defined as "of, or relating to, a thing's number in a series".